# How to enforce no abuse of definitions?

Tags: definition, fake-proofs, formal-proofs

I am writing a [proof assistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_assistant), in which a user can define a [propositional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus), and start creating theorems, which are automatically verified.

The problem I have ran into, comes from that I want the user to be able to define arbitrary additional (meta) notation on top of the propositional calculus, for convenience.

For example, suppose the user creates a [Hilbert system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system), which only uses the operators $\{\neg,\to\}$, and would like to define dysjunction as $A\vee B:=\neg A\to B$. This, by itself, is no problem, because I can simply compile formulas which contain these meta-symbols down into formulas which only contain $\neg$ and $\to$.

> But how to I enforce, or formalize, that definitions must not inflict with the underling logic? For example, a user could define $A:=\neg A$, and by the [principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion), prove any theorem they'd like (even false theorems)?

An initial but naïve idea would be to assert that the LHS of the definitions must contain only new operators. But this too can be abused. For example, here's another "proof" which leads to the principle of explosion. Define $B\circ B:=A\to B$

$$
\begin{align}
\text{1. }&B\to B\text{ (instance of identity)}\\
\text{2. }&(B\to B) \to B\circ B\text{ (by definition of $\circ$)}\\
\text{3. }&B\circ B\text{ (by (1) and (2) from modus ponens)}\\
\text{4. }&B\circ B \to (A\to B)\text{ (by definition of $\circ$))}\\
\text{5. }&A\to B \text{ (by (3) and (4) from modus ponens))}
\end{align}
$$

thus we have "proven" that $A\to B$ is always true (which it is obviously not, especially in our Hilbert system).

Any and all advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your list, how is 2. justified ?

Comment: @Peter Well, exactly! That's my problem. It's not, because it's an abuse of notation. But my proof assistant can't tell the difference Because $B\to B$ is of the form of $A\to B$ which is the definition of $B\circ B$.

Comment: Here , It is wrong to State (4) , where somehow , unknown (unintroduced) $A$ enters the argument.

Comment: In other words , using analogy , $f(x)=x+1$ is valid , $f(x)=x+y+7$ is not valid.

Comment: See [Definitions: Conservativeness and eliminability](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/definitions/#ConEli): "Conservativeness criterion (syntactic formulation): Any formula of 
$L$ [the basic language) that is provable in $L^+$ (the "extended" language) is provable in $L$.
.

Comment: @Prem that's a good example, but I'm unsure of how to generalize that as a "rule" which definitions must obey, and additionally show that it can't be abused as well in some way.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Great! I think that is what I was looking for.

Comment: You could make a rule that Definitions with new terms on LHS must use those terms on the RHS while not using unintroduced terms. Hence [[Eg1]] $f(x)$ can use $x$ , not $y$ [[Eg2]] $F(X,Y)$ can use $X$ , $Y$ , not $Z$ .... The **Checking** can be automated. It is easy to enforce.